# Postman save and lock (prevent editing) request / collection

Tags: postman

In Postman, once you have created a request or collection and have fine tuned it, is there any way to lock it so as to make it read only so that it can't be accidentally altered?

Obviously I would need something to toggle it back to editable again!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a option to make a collection read only for admin ( the creator of the collection). Few of the way of avoiding unnecessary changes are:

1. if you can edit rights of other users within the workspace make
   it view only for  selected users inside the workspace.
2. Create a fork of the collection so that you revert back
3. Create a copy of the collection
4. Download collection as json file

Personally i prefere downloading collection as json as this keeps the workspace clean and tidy .

**else:**

i prefer creating inprogress workspace and final workspace and sharing completed collection to final workspace and deleting it from ingrogress workspace everytime i finish something.

If changes is required , i will work in inprogress workspace by creating a copy